# How to get data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape data from one web page. My code looks like this:

```
grad = s.get('https://www.njuskalo.hr/prodaja-kuca/zagreb',headers=header, proxies=proxyDict)
city_soup = BeautifulSoup(grad.text, "lxml")
kvarts = city_soup.find_all(id="locationId_level_1")
print kvarts[0]
print "++++++++++++++++++++++="

for kvart in kvarts[0]:
    print kvart
```

As result I get:

```
<option data-url-alias="/brezovica" value="1247">Brezovica</option>
<option data-url-alias="/crnomerec" value="1248">Črnomerec</option>
<option data-url-alias="/donja-dubrava" value="1249">Donja Dubrava</option>
```

From there I need to extract data-url-alias and value.
How to do that?

Comment: use basic string manipulation? or easier just use regex

Comment: See the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes).

Answer (score 6):

`bs4` stores tag attributes in a dictionary so you can select them by name.

```
for kvart in kvarts[0].find_all('option'):
    print kvart['data-url-alias'], kvart['value']
```

As mentioned by Evyatar Meged in the comments this will raise a `KeyError` if a key doesn't exist, so if you're not sure about it use the `.get` method.

```
for kvart in kvarts[0].find_all('option'):
    print kvart.get('data-url-alias'), kvart.get('value')
```

[`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) returns `None` if a key doesn't exist (or you can set a default value)

Comment: I think it is better if he used `.get` to avoid `KeyError` being raised. still +1

Comment: @EvyatarMeged you're absolutely right, i'll update.

Comment: I knew you would definitely come up with any explanation. So, I was heading to the right direction as well, right? Thank you so much.

Comment: @robots.txt I think this is one of those situations where selenium may be the most reliable option. I hope I can help more the next time. Cheers!